# gitlab-ci docker-in-docker access to insecure registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

When configuring a gitlab-ci for building docker images and pushing them to my gitlab's insecure registry, I encountered several errors.  My gitlab-ci.yaml is laid out below:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: XXX:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

# The insecure-registry flag 
services:
  - docker:dind

build_container:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin

  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE
```

The first error was:

```
  $ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN myregistry.gitlab.com
  WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
  Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect 
  to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon 
  running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
  Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the 
  docker daemon running?
```

This was resolved by updating the login command to

```
echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" myregistry.gitlab.com --password-stdin
```

Unfortunately after updating, I encountered another error:

```
$ echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" myregistry.gitlab.com --password-stdin
Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry.gitlab.com/v2/: dial tcp XX.XX.XXX.XXX:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

How Can I resolve this?

Answer (score 52):

Like any other docker installation, it is necessary to instruct the docker daemon to allow connections to insecure registries.  In order to do this in the context of the docker-in-docker service, one must pass this configuration to the service.  This can be done by updating your gitlab-ci.yaml to specify the service as:

```
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=myregistry.gitlab.com"]
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks

Comment: @mcguip do you know some way to use an environment variable in this context ($CI_REGISTRY)?

Comment: @mathiasfk,  The example already uses several environment variables. Is there something more specific you’re after?

Comment: I mean using something like `command: ["--insecure-registry=$CI_REGISTRY"]`. In this case the context belongs to the runner, so the variable is not visible to the service.

Comment: I see. A good question; however, I don't have the answer off the top of my head nor could I find anything in the docker documentation.  Perhaps you might raise as a separate question as this would more generally apply to variable substitution in dockerfile command statements.

Comment: To use variables and pass them to dind, have a look at https://github.com/LordGaav/dind-options/

Comment: You also need the port, at least if you are using an IP address: `command: ["--tls=false", "--insecure-registry=192.168.34.20:5000"]`